# Why are discalced Carmelites discalced?

Tags: religious-orders, clothing, carmelites

Why are discalced Carmelites discalced (don't wear shoes)?

I think there are other religious orders that don't wear shoes, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 16th-century Spain, "discalced" was a common ecclesiastical term that indicated "reformed". The Augustinian Recollects were and are still known as Discalced Augustinians. They were founded in 1588 in Toledo, Spain. Reformed Franciscans who organized themselves in 16th-century Spain, too, adopted the name "discalced".

More than one Discalced Carmelite community describes the term "discalced" in these or similar words:

> “Discalced” comes from the Latin word meaning “unshod,” and they were so called because the most distinctive thing about their appearance was that, in keeping with their more austere way of life, they wore the rope sandals of the poor in place of leather shoes. This was also a sign to the world of their poverty of spirit and simplicity of life. It was a reminder of the biblical stories where the people removed their shoes to stand barefoot, humble, on holy ground in the presence of God.

Further reading:

- [Donovan, S. (1909). Discalced. In The Catholic Encyclopedia. New York: Robert Appleton Company.](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/05028a.htm)
- [Gallagher, L. (2020). History of Carmelite Order. Brighton, Massachusetts: Washington Province, Secular Order of Discalced Carmelites.](https://www.ocdswashprov.org/history-of-carmelite-order)

Comment: So it means they wear sandals and not shoes?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: @Geremia Speaking as a Carmelite, sandals are the footwear of choice but not obligatory, especially in climates that call for shoes and socks, not sandals. Although "unshod" is the derivation of the term "discalced", the concept of "reform" remains the primary meaning of the term "discalced".